# How to get height of a scrolling element in angular

Tags: angular

I know how to get a height of an element. Can anyone help me how to get the height of a scrolling element.
I have a slackblitz example here. I set max-height to 200px, it gives me that as the height. But, I wanna know actual height of the element. Thanks.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-element-height-btomm4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[scrollHeight](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp)** property of the scrollable element,

```
{{ getHeight.scrollHeight }}
```

**[Forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/scroll-height-example?file=app/app.component.html)**